# Regex to remove after a year in forma YYYY or YY

Tags: regex

I have the string: **25 de novembro de 2020\xa0(60\xa0anos)**

For this particular case the regex `(?<=\d{4})(.*$)`, and gives me the match **25 de novembro de 2020**, but with **13 de outubro de 54\xa0(63\xa0anos)Roma, Itália, Império Romano** not. How can i make a regex to match both cases?

I'm doing in python.

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
string = '348/347 a.C. (70 anos) 399 a.C. (70 anos) 13 de outubro de 54 (63 anos)Roma, ca. 470 a.C. (70 anos) 25 de novembro de 2020 (60 anos) 29 de setembro de 1908 (69 anos)Rio de Janeiro, DF Estados Unidos do Brasil'

re.sub(r'([\w\. /]+) \(\d+ anos\)(?:[A-Za-z]+,?)*(?: [A-Za-z]+,?(?!\w*\.))*',r'\1',string)

#result is
#348/347 a.C. 399 a.C. 13 de outubro de 54 ca. 470 a.C. 25 de novembro de 2020 29 de setembro de 1908
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i want the opposite: everything after the year (yyyy or yy) must be delete. 
E.g.: 25 de novembro de 2020\xa0(60\xa0anos) turns to 25 de novembro de 2020. The \xa0 can be any type of space or character.

Comment: What if i have a date with "a.c" in the end? It's possible to make an or condition to match this case too?

Comment: Can you provide an example? @Fabricio Silva

Comment: For sure. let's say that i have text strings like these:

348/347 a.C. (70 anos)
399 a.C. (70 anos)
13 de outubro de 54 (63 anos)Roma,
ca. 470 a.C. (70 anos)
25 de novembro de 2020 (60 anos)

all I need to do is split the string exactly after the year, whether it's in yyyy or yy or yyyy|yyy|yy a.c format. Everything before that must be kept.

Example: 
- 399 a.C. (70 anos) === 399 a.C.
- 13 de outubro de 54 (63 anos)Roma .. === 13 de outubro de 54
- ca. 470 a.C. (70 anos) === ca. 470 a.C.
 - 6 de julho de 1976 (89 anos) Pequim, Rep... === 6 de julho de 1976

And so on. Any tip?

Comment: i changed pattern now it will work great.

Comment: Almost there man! xD
Your way: 13 de outubro de 54 (63 anos)Roma == 13 de outubro de 54Roma,
but what i need is: 13 de outubro de 54 (63 anos)Roma = 13 de outubro de 54

Comment: modified pattern again

Comment: Dear @arutar, please read this if you can, i explain with more details here, a gist in github:
[link](https://gist.github.com/faahiero/676da6269c5726b7b9216f1d910149aa)

Comment: Does your long long string have any delimiter. separator

Comment: Try this new one regex pattern and be happy!